# error: 'listOfColors' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and I don't understand why I'm getting a `not declared` error on this:

```
int main(){
    string listOfColors[5] = {"red","blue","green","yellow","magenta"};
    for(int i = 0;i < sizeof listofColors;i++){
        cout << listofColors[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first utilization of an array so far, so I may just not be declaring it correctly. I also had the array declaration before the main function beforehand.

Comment: Note that this is a wrong use of `sizeof`. `sizeof` gives you number of bytes, not number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your variable as `listOfColors` (capital "O"), and then you use it as `listofColors` in your `for` loop. All you need to do is to capitalize the "O" when using your variable.